# Released app does not work as the original

Tags: c++, qt

I have a file with hundreds and hundreds of pictures (photographs) that I need to show in preview to some people. This preview should be a purchase order (rapidly, nothing "pro") and I would give them so that the people can put a cross in the case they want a picture and which size (as simple as that).

I tried to auto-generate the purchase order, there would be two per page (A4) on a PDF.

I use Qt/C++ and three objects :

QPdfWriter
QPainter
QImage

Here's the beginning of the pdf-generation class :

```
int order = 1;
qDebug() << "pdf creation";

QString logoName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Sélectionner le logo", QString(), "Images (*.png *.bmp *.jpg)");

QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0, "Export PDF",
                                                QString(), "*.pdf");

QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, "Sélectionner le dossier de photos");

QFont titleFont("Arial", 24);
titleFont.setUnderline(true);

QFont textFont("Times new roman", 12);

QDirIterator it(dir);

if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
    if (QFileInfo(fileName).suffix().isEmpty())
        fileName.append(".pdf");
    QPdfWriter writer(fileName);

    QPainter painter(&writer);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    int height = painter.device()->height();
    int semi = height/2;
    int width = painter.device()->width();
    int digits = 1;

    qDebug() << "height : " << height << " width : " << width;

    QImage logo(logoName);
    QImage finalLogo = logo.scaled(3750, 1250, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);




    while(it.hasNext()){
        it.next();
        digits = countDigits(order);
        if(it.fileInfo().isFile()){
            if(order%2!=0){
                painter.drawImage(300,100,finalLogo);
                QImage currentPreview(it.filePath());
                QImage finalPreview = currentPreview.scaled(3250,4000, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
                painter.drawImage(650,1500,finalPreview);
```

The rest is just the drawing of the text/borders.

I tried it in debug : works fine
I compiled in release, put all the .dll in the file (including platform) and ran it without Qt : works fine

Then I put the files on a usb stick, I put it on the other computer that I use for the pictures, that computer does NOT have Qt.
I launched the .exe and the app showed exactly as on my dev-pc

But when I called the PDF creation I filled the FileDialogs with my data, it runs for around 30 secs (a lot of pictures in the file) and generates the PDF.

I opened it and ... not a single picture on the PDF.

All the lines and texts are in place without any problem, it generates the right amount of purchase order but not a single picture on it ... Neither the logo `(QImage finalLogo)` nor the preview `(QImage finalPreview)`.

It's like `QPainter::drawText()/drawLine()` does work, but not `QPainter::drawImage`.

It's disturbing since it works on a computer but not on another ... Did I do something wrong when compiling/releasing ?

Comment: Could it be an issue with file permissions on the directory where the photos are kept? Are the photo files readable?? If you run your app as administrator/root (you don't indicate your host OS), does that help???

Comment: What format are these images? Perhaps you're missing the image plugins?

Comment: The files are readable, i tried to put them in other directories, i also tried to run the app as administrator (windows) and it's still not working on the non-dev pc. The images are .jpg

Comment: You can try to redirect debug logs to a file for release mode and then investigate that file to check what's going wrong.

Comment: You need image plugins for .jpg files. Look for `qjpg.dll`.

Comment: Ok ! I figured it out. The dll to handle the jpeg was not in the right directory, i moved it to the right one and it worked. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Dranna You can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

([Answered in the comments - converted to a community wiki.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

The OP wrote:

> Ok ! I figured it out. The dll to handle the jpeg was not in the right directory, I moved it to the right one and it worked.

Comment: There's no point cluttering up the home page  by bumping old uninteresting questions like this. Voting to close is better.